# Could not load type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm getting a error when I try to debug a code that reads Excel files. I'm wondering if the reference to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application' is wrong, I get the following error.

isn't the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` version suppose to be 12? and not loaded from my project assembly?

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'
>   from assembly 'Dialog,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The type is
>   marked as eligible for type
>   equivalence, but the containing
>   assembly is not loaded as fully
>   trusted.

When I try to debug the code I get the exception before I can step into the function.

```
DataTable data = ExcelImport.GetDataFromFile(file);
```

My function

```
public static DataSet GetDataFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        Application oXL;
        Workbook oWB;
        Worksheet oSheet;
        Range oRng;

        // Needed to fix culture problem with excel files.
        CultureInfo cult = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        try
        {
            //  creat a Application object
            oXL = new Application();
            //   get   WorkBook  object
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            //   get   WorkSheet object
            oSheet = (Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("dtExcel");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int jValue = oSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Columns.Count;
            int iValue = oSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Rows.Count;
            //  get data columns
            for (int j = 1; j <= jValue; j++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("column" + j, Type.GetType("System.String"));
            }

            //  get data in cell
            for (int i = 1; i <= iValue; i++)
            {
                var test = (Range)oSheet.Cells[i, 1];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test.Text))
                {
                    DataRow dr = ds.Tables["dtExcel"].NewRow();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= jValue; j++)
                    {
                        oRng = (Range)oSheet.Cells[i, j];
                        string strValue = oRng.Text.ToString();
                        dr["column" + j] = strValue;
                    }
                    ds.Tables["dtExcel"].Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            oXL.Workbooks.Close();
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cult;
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error reading excel file", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using the C# 4.0 compiler, try turning off Embedding Interop Assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vcsjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones) commend got me on the correct track. after turning off Embedding Interop Assemblies I needed to edit the web.config to trust Excel

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

Comment: Glad that worked. I've had trouble using the Office PIA as embedded Interop Assemblies. Since most machines will have it in the GAC anyway, it's best to just turn it off for Office PIA's.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a bad reference, not bad code.  Has this code ever worked?  Have you tried removing the reference to the Excel Interop and re-adding it again?  Since it doesn't even get into your method, my assumption is that when the system tries to load the reference dll, it crashes.