# After deploying Website - Could not load type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application from assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, web-deployment

After the creation of a website on my system, I deployed it on the server but started getting this error, as an alert from the page.

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application' from assembly 'xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   The type is marked as eligible for type equivalence, but the containing assembly is not loaded as fully trusted.

I am stuck at this and unable to understand the problem

Comment: do you have MS Word installed on server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858089/could-not-load-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application

Comment: @AntonNorko It is the Shared Hosting. I have no idea whether MS Word is installed.

Comment: @joe_young this does not help. I tried this already.

Comment: @kamalpreet I'm afraid if you have no installed MS Word on server - it will never work, because Interop library have only interface, but it is wrapper for native office dlls also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid if you have no installed MS Word on server - it will never work, because Interop library have only interface, but it is wrapper for native office dlls also. If you just need to read/write MS Word document - you can do it not only via interop approach. There are a lot of (non)commercial libraries for that. 
Alternatives:

[Office XML sdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb448854.aspx) provided by Microsoft. A bit low leveled solution. But it works.

[DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/) much better and high leveled solution for create/read/write MS Word files without MS Word installed.

Cheers.

Comment: I need to convert a word document into PDF. Is it possible with any of these?

Comment: @kamalpreet No, it's just creates docs from scratch. Regarding PDF conversion: may be better would be to have completed pdf template with named (not)readonly  fields and use specific pdf library to create new pdf from template and fillup fields you need. Good PDF library for that is iTextSharp - more low leveled abstraction or PdfClown - high leveled abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like one of the many problems related to [Microsoft KB: Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). Using Office Interop server-side isn't recommended or supported.

I'd recommend you look into [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com) (it's much easier than OpenXML) to generate docx files on the server.